# Why does any(any(A)) work where any(A) doesn't?

Tags: matlab, any

So I have the following code which is a simple if statement with a pop up box. My question is why does this not work when I use any(error==1) instead of any(any(error == 1))?

```
K=100
error = zeros(K,28)

%lots of other code

error(K,2)=1                     %this is here as a test to trigger the true logic statement
if any(any(error==1))
    disp('hello')
    f = figure;
    h = uicontrol('Position',[20 20 50 40],'String','Ok','Callback','uiresume(gcbf)');
    uiwait(gcf); 
    close(f);
end
```

I have my code working but want to understand the workings of the "any" function.

Comment: Executing your code followed by "any(error==1)" returns no error on my system. Is it that a vector is being returned that's the problem?

Comment: Since `error` is a 2D matrix, `any(error==1)` which is essentially `any(error==1,1)`, would be a row vector and if you use it with `IF` conditional, it has to be all `ones/true` to get into the IF part. But with `any(any(error == 1))` which would be a scalar and for this to be `one/true`, any one of the elements from the earlier obtained row vector has to be `one/true`. So, to summarize, `any(any(error == 1))` is little more "considerate" than `any(error == 1)`.

Comment: Ok. I suspected that this was probably the cause but I didn't realise that IF would need to be fully filled with ones to trigger the TRUE. Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `if` statement.

The `if` statement needs 1 logical to continue. If it has more than 1 input, it needs ALL of them to be true.

In your code:

```
>> any(error==1)

ans =

  Columns 1 through 18

     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 19 through 28

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

and

```
>> any(any(error==1))

ans =

     1
```

Therefore it the first case, as ALL the index of the vector are not true, it will skip the if, however in the second one, as the answer is 1 it executes the code.

Try this and see it for yourself

```
if [0 1]
   disp('This is not going to be displayed')
end
if [1 1]
   disp('Hellooo, this will!')
end
if any([0 1])
   disp('Yay! this also!')
end
```